# How to overwrite attributes in OOP inheritance with Python dataclass

Tags: python, oop, python-dataclasses

Currently, I've some code that looks like this, with the irrelevant methods removed.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, List

@dataclass
class A:
    S0: int
    K: int
    r: float = 0.05
    T: int = 1
    N: int = 2
    StockTrees: List[float] = field(init=False, default_factory=list)
    pu: Optional[float] = 0
    pd: Optional[float] = 0
    div: Optional[float] = 0
    sigma: Optional[float] = 0
    is_put: Optional[bool] = field(default=False)
    is_american: Optional[bool] = field(default=False)
    is_call: Optional[bool] = field(init=False)
    is_european: Optional[bool] = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.is_call = not self.is_put
        self.is_european = not self.is_american
        
    @property
    def dt(self):
        return self.T/float(self.N)
    
    @property
    def df(self):
        return math.exp(-(self.r - self.div) * self.dt)

@dataclass
class B(A):

    u: float = field(init=False)
    d: float = field(init=False)
    qu: float = field(init=False)
    qd: float = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.u = 1 + self.pu
        self.d = 1 - self.pd
        self.qu = (math.exp((self.r - self.div) * self.dt) - self.d)/(self.u - self.d)
        self.qd = 1 - self.qu
    
    
@dataclass
class C(B):
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.u = math.exp(self.sigma * math.sqrt(self.dt))
        self.d = 1/self.u
        self.qu = (math.exp((self.r - self.div)*self.dt) - self.d)/(self.u - self.d)
        self.qd = 1 - self.qu
```

Basically, I have a class `A` where it defines some attributes that all of its child classes will share, so it's only really meant to be initialised via the instantiation of its child classes and its attributes are to be inherited by its child classes. The child class `B` is meant to be a process which does some calculation which is inherited by `C` which does a variation of the same calculation. `C` basically inherits all the methods from `B` and its only difference is that its calculation of `self.u` and `self.d` are different.

One can run the code by either using `B` calculation which requires arguments `pu` and `pd` or `C` calculation which requires argument `sigma`, as below

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    am_option = B(50, 52, r=0.05, T=2, N=2, pu=0.2, pd=0.2, is_put=True, is_american=True)
    print(f"{am_option.sigma = }")
    print(f"{am_option.pu = }")
    print(f"{am_option.pd = }")
    print(f"{am_option.qu = }")
    print(f"{am_option.qd = }")
    
    eu_option2 = C(50, 52, r=0.05, T=2, N=2, sigma=0.3, is_put=True)
    print(f"{am_option.sigma = }")
    print(f"{am_option.pu = }")
    print(f"{am_option.pd = }")
    print(f"{am_option.qu = }")
    print(f"{am_option.qd = }")
```

which gives the output

```
am_option.pu = 0.2
am_option.pd = 0.2
am_option.qu = 0.6281777409400603
am_option.qd = 0.3718222590599397
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dazza/option_pricer/test.py", line 136, in <module>
    eu_option2 = C(50, 52, r=0.05, T=2, N=2, sigma=0.3, is_put=True)
  File "<string>", line 15, in __init__
  File "/home/dazza/option_pricer/test.py", line 109, in __post_init__
    super().__post_init__()
  File "/home/dazza/option_pricer/test.py", line 55, in __post_init__
    self.qu = (math.exp((self.r - self.div) * self.dt) - self.d)/(self.u - self.d)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

So instantiating `B` works fine since it successfully calculated the values `pu`,`pd`,`qu` and `qd`. However, my problem comes when the instantiation of `C` is unable to calculate `qu` since `pu` and `pd` are zeros by default, making it divide by 0.

My question: How can I fix this so that `C` inherits all the attributes initialisation (including `__post_init__`) of `A` and all methods of `B`, and at the same time have its calculation of `self.u = math.exp(self.sigma * math.sqrt(self.dt))` and `self.d = 1/self.u` **overwriting** `self.u = 1 + self.pu` and `self.d = 1 - self.pd` of `B`, as well as keeping `self.qu` and `self.qd` the same?(they're the same for `B` and `C`)

Comment: Would you really want to call `super().__post_init__()` in class C if the calculation differs from that in class B?

Comment: What would be the alternative here? Calling `A().__post_init__()` instead? If I do that I get `A().__post_init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'S0' and 'K'` and I don't know where to go from there? I'm still learning my way around OOP.

Comment: When you instantiate C you don't get a new instance of B and A - it is simply that C also has the attributes of B and A. So there is no way to overwrite self.qu on B becuase that doesn't exist.  self.qu and self.qd are on C, and when you run the method you inherit from B it uses the attributes on your instance of C.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Instantiation of `C` would've inherited the attributes from `A` and `B`, including `u` and `d` of `B` right?. Is there not a way to write it so that instantiating `C` will have its `u` and `d` replacing the inherited `u` and `d` from `B`?

Comment: Can you set your non-init attributes independently of the other values? I question whether *any* of them should be instance attributes rather than (read-only) properties.

Comment: @chepner Are you referring to the `is_call` and `is_european`?

Comment: Those, as pointed out in an answer to your previous question, as well as `u` and `d`. Can these values change independently of `pu` and `pd` (or at all, over the lifetime of the instance)? I don't know what you are actually calculating, but some of these seem like they could even be candidates to be local variables in whatever method is doing the calculation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically if `B` is instantiated, it'll require inputs `pu` and `pd` to calculate `qu` and `qd`. If `C` is instantiated, it'll require input `sigma` to calculate `qu` and `qd` and here `pu` and `pd` will thus be its default value of 0 and shouldn't affect object of `C`.

Comment: @user3613025 - there is nothing to stop C having different values of any attribute you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports multiple inheritance.  You can inherit from `A` before `B`, which means any overlapping methods will be taken from `A` (such as `__post_init__`).  Any code you write in class `C` will overwrite what's inherited from `A` and `B`.  If you need to have more control over which methods come from which class, you can always define the method in `C` and make a function call to `A` or `B` (like `A.dt(self)`).

```py
class C(A, B):
    ...
```

ANOTHER EDIT:
I just saw that `A` initializes some stuff you want in `C`. Because `C`'s parent is now `A` (if you used my code above), you can add back in the `super().__post_init__()` line to `C`'s `__post_init__` so that it calls `A`'s `__post_init__`.
If this doesn't work, you can always just put `A.__post_init__(self)` in the `__post_init__` of `C`.

Comment: The division by 0 shouldn't be a problem if `C` was able to overwrite `self.u` and `self.d` of `B`, which is why I'm asking if there's a way to do that.

Comment: If B already inherits from A, making C inherit from A directly as well seems to be pointless to be honest.

Comment: Thanks :) . It however now gives `AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'is_call'`. I think the problem here is that `is_call` is defined in the `__post_init__` of `A` which is somehow not initiated. Should it?

Comment: Also `is_call` is used in one of the methods of `B` but I just didn't put the methods in above.

Comment: I have `C` inherit from `A` because they want everything all the methods from `A`, but also some methods from `B`, so `A` needs to be inherited first so `B` doesn't override it in `C`.

Comment: Just made another edit that should fix the `is_call` error

Comment: Amazing! I think it was actually a combination of your answer with Chepner's that did the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Define another method to initialize `u` and `d`, so that you can override *that* part of `B` without overriding how `qu` and `qd` are defined.

```
@dataclass
class B(A):

    u: float = field(init=False)
    d: float = field(init=False)
    qu: float = field(init=False)
    qd: float = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self._define_u_and_d()
        self.qu = (math.exp((self.r - self.div) * self.dt) - self.d)/(self.u - self.d)
        self.qd = 1 - self.qu

    def _define_u_and_d(self):
        self.u = 1 + self.pu
        self.d = 1 - self.pd



@dataclass
class C(B):
    def _define_u_and_d(self):
        self.u = math.exp(self.sigma * math.sqrt(self.dt))
        self.d = 1/self.u
```

Comment: This almost looks like what I need. However, I don't think that `C` is inheriting `self.is_call` from the `__post_init__` of `A`, since in my actual code where `self.is_call` is used in one of the methods of `B`(that gets inherited by `C`), it says `AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'is_call'`

Comment: Impossible to diagnose given the code you've shown. `C` inherits `__post_init__` from `B`, which calls `A.__post_init__` via `super`.